# Want to add table row contains form tag Dynamically in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add dynamically a table row which contains the form as

```
<tr><form><td>Input type</td><td>Submit Form</td></tr></form>
```

but i am failed to got the exact result my JavaScript file as follow:

```
 //adding new row for table in upcoming classes module.
var counter = 0;

$("#addrow").on("click", function () {
    var newRow = $("<tr><form id="scheudleTable1">");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="student_name' + counter + '"></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"  name="attendance_info' + counter + '"></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="feedbackInfo' + counter + '"></td>';
    cols += '<td>';
    cols += '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  value="Add"> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
    cols += '<input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-sm btn-danger"  value="X">';
    cols += '</td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $("table.studentList").append(newRow);
    counter++;
});



$("table.studentList").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();       
    counter -= 1
});
```

and my html file is look like this:

```
<tr>
<form id="scheudleTable1"></form>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="student_name0"></td><td><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="attendance_info0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="feedbackInfo0"></td>
<td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" value="Add"> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="X"></td></tr>
```

Please help to get the result like:

```
<tr>
<form id="myTable">
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="student_name0"></td><td><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="attendance_info0"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="feedbackInfo0"></td>
<td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" value="Add"> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="X"></td></form></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

create one  table `<table id="tableData">` after that write the all `<td>` in single line as follows

`var cols= '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="student_name' + counter + '"></td><td><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"  name="attendance_info' + counter + '"></td>';`

after that append it to the table id using

```
$('#tableData').append(cols);
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

https://jsfiddle.net/shashikantk1992/Lysu9nob/4/

```
     //adding new row for table in upcoming classes module.
var counter = 0;
var scheudleTable1='mytable';
$("#addrow").on("click", function () {
//alert('asd');

    var newRow = $("<form id='"+scheudleTable1+"'><tr>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="student_name' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"  name="attendance_info' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="feedbackInfo' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td>';
    cols += '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  value="Add"> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
    cols += '<input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-sm btn-danger"  value="X"/>';
    cols += '</td>';
   newRow.append(cols);
    $("table.studentList").append(newRow);
    counter++;

});



$("table.studentList").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    $(this).closest("form").remove();       
    counter -= 1
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help, i have already tried this but my css is not in proper manner, when i tried this.

Comment: ok, but i think you can modify ur css accordingly. so that both can work.